# Script não seguro

Tags: php, javascript, script

Estou desenvolvendo um website com 2 scripts. Porém ao enviar o site para área de testes, os scripts não carregam, como na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que devo fazer para serem executados automaticamente e ser reconhecido como seguro?

Comment: Que scripts são esses?

Comment: são scripts de fadeIn() e fadeOut() de divs e outro de "pesquisa de cidades atendidas", com mysql

Comment: Dá uma olhada na resposta e faça um teste, por favor. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isto acontece quando você tenta carregar algum conteúdo HTTP dentro de uma página HTTPS, como por exemplo, um JavaScript:

```
             ERRADO
               ↓
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis..."></script>


              CORRETO
                 ↓
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis..."></script>


          CORRETO (veja nota)
             ↓
<script src="//ajax.googleapis..."></script>
```

**Nota:** Sem especificar o protocolo só funciona quando a URL remota aceita ambos os protocolos HTTP e HTTPS.

Comment: obrigado! funcionou com sua ajuda. :)